# Very different times between time.clock() and App Engine log time

Tags: python, app-engine-flexible

I try to troubleshoot latency issues in my App Engine flex app, and I suspect that my server takes way too long to answer (the TTFB, given by Chrome, is more than 20sec).

So I use `time.clock()` (Python2.7) to see where the time is spent. I also use `print` to get those values into Stackdriver.

And the different times are not consistent at all.

[image]
This is just after entering my function (it's actually my route handler)

[image]
And here is just before leaving it.
The elapsed time I compute is nothing but end time - start time (one call to `time.clock()` each).

And you can see it gives less than one sec. The stackdriver logs show that almost 4 sec is spent.

Any idea why this difference ? `time.clock()` isn't working as expected on App engine flex ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.clock()` is giving you the amount of CPU time of the process and that is why the values are inconsistent.

I did this test:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    tc0 = time.clock()
    print(tc0)
    tt0 = time.time()
    print(tt0)
    x= datetime.datetime.now()
    print(x)

    time.sleep(10)

    tc1 = time.clock()
    print(tc1)
    tt1 = time.time()
    print(tt1)
    y = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(y)

    return 'Hello World!'
```

And this are the results:

```
tc0  0.144582
tt0  1552994288.7333689
x    2019-03-19 11:18:08.733498

tc1  0.144829
tt1  1552994298.7438576
y    2019-03-19 11:18:18.743877
```

As you can see, what you want to use is `time.time()` or `datetime.datetime.now()` to get the real time spent in a given portion of code since `time.clock()` is giving you the amount of CPU time.